# Hystrix FallBack Bad Practice

Tags: java, spring, hystrix

Why is it a bad practice to have database call in the fallback method when using hystrix library?

```
@HystrixCommand(fallbackMethod ="fallBackMethod")
public Double getRating(){
 //Some Code Here
}
public Double fallBackMethod(){
//Any call to data base
}
```

Comment: If your database is down, the fallback will also fail... See Hystrix wiki for more details : https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#Fallback

Comment: Thank you Thoomas

Comment: It is not bad if you call another database but in this case you should use implement a fallback for that fallback, you turn around.

Comment: will it have any cascading effect on the failure

Answer (score 0):

If your database is down or slow, then your call in the fallback will slow or block or throw exception. In some worse case, many threads will block in the fallback, so your service is probably to unavailable.

The fallback is to protect your service. When there is something wrong, the call will fail fast or silently by calling fallback, thus the thread won't be block and the service is still able to serve. So it's not recommend to do something heavily or unstable in the fallback, for example, call a database.

If you have to do so, you can use HystrixCommand in your fallback, just like this: https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/How-To-Use#Common-Patterns-FallbackCacheViaNetwork

Answer (score 0):

It's NOT a bad practice to have db call in a fallback, if your business logic requires to do so. Just make sure that this fallback method is also wrapped with @HystrixCommand as it can timeout due to db issue.